# Which is the fastest embedded noSQL database for Python?

Tags: python, nosql

I need a noSQL solution that is fast, small, embedded (because I don't have root privilege) and supports Python. For now I just have two names: DyBASE, CodernityDB. Please help me find others and choose the best one. Thank you!!!

Comment: Non-embedded databases can work under nonprivileged user accounts.

Comment: The *fastest* for what use-case? A database can be lightning fast when doing one thing, but sluggishly slow when doing another.

Answer (score 1):

ZODB - It is not "small", I guess - but it is fast, it is native to Python - and it can certainly be installed without root privileges using `buildout` or even only virtualenv -

Here is a blog post showing how ZODB compares against sqlite - (and sqlite, in its turn, for single threaded code, performes quite well against larger SQL database systems  - just look for benchmarks):

http://pyinsci.blogspot.com.br/2007/09/zodb-vs-relational-database-simple.html

Here is a link to the tutorial -
for being able to install it as in the tutorial, without adm privileges on the system,
first create a virtualenv and activate it:

http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/documentation/tutorial.html

Here is the link for ZODB and install instructions:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB3/3.8.2